# Inserting items of vector to set

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

I want to insert items of `vector` string to `set` string in c++. If the item of the vector contains `'+'`, It should be added to one set, else it should be added to another set. I can do it by iterating the vector one by one. But Could I do this by '`callback`' function of '`insert`' function of '`set`'?

```
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const std::string& str) const{
        if(str.find("+") != std::string::npos) {
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};
std::vector strlist = {"apple","+apple","banana","orange","+graphes"};
std::set<std::string,compare> set1,set2;
set1.insert(strlist.begin(),strlist.end(),compare);
```

I want to create a list of `set1` with the items,

```
apple,
banana,
orange
```

and `set2` with the items of,

```
+apple
+graphes
```

Comment: Please don't do `if(condition) return false; else return true;`, just do: `return !condition;`.

Comment: You are not implementing the correct `compare` operator. `std::set` wants a functor for `<` (`LessThan`), not for `==` (`Equals`). [More info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: The comparison function passed to a `std::set` defines the order the elements are arranged inside, *not* to select if an element shall be inserted or not! The comparison function shall compare two objects `a` and `b` such that if `compare(a, b)` returns true, then `a` shall be sorted before `b` in the set.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Could it be that there's no overload of [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) that takes a comparator? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). As for what you want to do, perhaps what you're looking for is [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `std::partition_copy` as follows:

```
std::partition_copy(strlist.begin(), strlist.end(),
                    std::inserter(set1, set1.end()),
                    std::inserter(set2, set2.end()),
                    [](const std::string& str) { return str.find("+") != std::string::npos; }))
```